# How can I strip commas and periods from a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have string containing something like this:

```php
"Favourite bands: coldplay, guns & roses, etc.,"
```

How can I remove commas and periods using `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You could use

```
preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $string);
```

but using a regular expression for simple character substitution is overkill.

You'd be better off using [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
strtr($string, array('.' => '', ',' => ''));
```

or [str_replace](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace(array('.', ','), '' , $string);
```

Comment: What about Unicode strings?