# How to fix character encoding in Wordpress title for comma, apostrophe or quotes?

Tags: html, wordpress, encoding, character, title

I'm using a custom function to fetch RSS feeds based on the Wordpress title.

Works great but if title contains a comma, apostrophe or quote it breaks the feed because it is submitting the html encoding as part of the RSS feed search URL.

The goal is to have the RSS feed search URL contain the exact text that's in the Wordpress title, without any html character encoding. I tried `html_entity_decode(get_the_title())` and it gets rid of apostrophe and quotes, but it does not work for commas. I'm guessing need to do a str_replace to get rid of commas but not sure the best way to go about it and also incorporate with the html_entity_decode function.

Here's the custom function I'm using (as a little custom plugin) for now. Thanks for your help!

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_rss', 'execute_custom_rss_shortcode' );
function execute_custom_rss_shortcode() {
  return do_shortcode('[wp_rss_retriever url="https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=' . get_the_title() . '&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen" items="10"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `preg_replace` to strip out all special-chars from the title by only allowing letters and numbers (no special chars), i updated your code and posted an example:

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_rss', 'execute_custom_rss_shortcode' );
function execute_custom_rss_shortcode() {
    $filtered_title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', get_the_title()); 

// Remove any special character from the title
    return do_shortcode('[wp_rss_retriever url="https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=' . $filtered_title . '&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen" items="10"]');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kradyy, that code let the RSS work if comma in title, but didn't work if there is an apostrophe (') in the title. The code I was using before RSS worked with apostrophe but not with the comma. Maybe I need to add something into the code like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822631/trouble-replacing-apostrophe-with-preg-replace
or this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471470/how-can-i-strip-commas-and-periods-from-a-string

Comment: I updated the regexp to work for all special characters, i noticed that the apostrophe was allowed in the last one :)

Comment: Turns out I was still having issues with the apostrophe (') breaking the RSS feed. So I tried using another preg-replace for get_the_title and then a str_replace to address the comma. Poking in the dark...but it's working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this code. It filters the commas, quotes and apostrophes from the title so that the RSS feed is not broken by HTML entities. Maybe not the ideal way, so any other better solutions are welcome!

```
    $filter_title = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i", '', get_the_title());
  return do_shortcode('[feed-fetcher feeds="https://www.bing.com/news/search?q=' . str_replace(',', '', $filter_title) . '&format=rss" max="6"]');
}
```